# Why there is difference in label assignment between String Label(id) and Integer Label(id) during pre assignment and user input variable

Tags: python, variables, label, google-colaboratory

Why there is a difference in label assignment between String Label(id) and Integer Label(id) during pre-assignment and user input variable

**A)Test1**

```
#case with Integer

a=3
b = input() #input is default i.e. String
c=3
d = int(input()) #input is type-casted to integer type
# consider input value for b and d is 3
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
print(id(c))
print(id(d))
print(a is b)
print(c is d)
```

***B)Test2***

```
#case with String

s1 = "abc"
s2 = input('Enter a String : ') 
# consider input value for s2= abc
print(s1 == s2)
print(s1 is s2)
s3 = "abc"
print(s1 is s3)
print(s2 is s3)
print(id(s1))
print(id(s2))
print(id(s3))
```

Comment: Can you print your results ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.